# Java date conversion to timezone not working

Tags: java, date

In java, I download a time from the UK and I am in toronto, I want to get the timezone and change the converted date object to it, but it's not working.

```
public static Date getDateFromSQLDate(String sqldate) {
    try {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(sqldate);

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.setTimeZone(tz);
        return calendar.getTime();

        //return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

DateFormat uses the system's default timezone, which most likely to be Toronto. What you need to do is:

```
 DateFormat formatter = ...
 formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
 Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(sqldate);
 return date;
```

Or whichever time zone identifier applicable to your "UK" time. You can see the list of supported identifier names here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Keep in mind that the Date object (or java.sql.Date) **never has any timezone information stored in it**. Saying you want to convert a timezone of a Date object just doesn't make any sense because you can't.

What you can do is to set the timezone from which you parse, or format the Date object.

Comment: The UK time is 5 hours ahead of toronto, is Europe/London right?

Comment: UK time is 5 hours ahead during winter, but might be 4 any other time depending on daylight savings adjustment.