# How to convert GMT datetime SQL data type to JAVA EST timestamp on JDK 1.7

Tags: java, date-formatting, jdk1.7

datetime datatype in GMT SQL server:
Column name = PostedDateTime
Value = 2019-09-30 17:46:04.600

I'm trying to use JAVA code to convert that datetime value to an EST timestamp
So the output should be:
2019-09-30 13:46:04

Any ideas how to convert this, please include the package that needs to be imported?

So far I have this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dr = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
SimpleDateFormat dr1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = obj.getStringProperty("S_DISCUSSION_POSTEDDATETIME");
Date date = dr.parse(dateString);           
strRetBuffer.append(obj.getStringProperty("S_DISCUSSION_AUTHOR") + ": " + dr1.format(date) + ": " + obj.getStringProperty("S_DISCUSSION_TOPICNAME")+": " +obj.getStringProperty("S_DISCUSSION_BODY") + "\n\r" );
```

Comment: Hi Eric. please share your code how you're trying to achieve your goal?

Comment: I have shared the code and I am not sure how to convert it to EST.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java date conversion to timezone not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810585/java-date-conversion-to-timezone-not-working)

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        String x = "2019-09-30 17:46:04.600";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = formatter.parse(x);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 3):

First parse the input string into `LocalDateTime` using `DateTimeFormatter`

```
String date = "2019-09-30 17:46:04.600";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime local = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
```

And then convert `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` with time zone `GMT` which is `UTC+0`

```
ZonedDateTime zone = ZonedDateTime.of(local, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

Finally convert the `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime` with `US/Eastern` and output format

```
String output = zone.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("US/Eastern")).toLocalDateTime().format(outputFormat);
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to have it done on JAVA JDK 1.7. The code that you provided only works on JDK 1.8 to obtain java.time.* class.

Comment: Yes, you can do this on JDK 1.7 since java.time (the modern Java date and time API introduced in Java 1.8) has been backported. Get [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), add it to your project, import from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages and enjoy how much nicer it is to work with compared to the old and poorly designed datetime classes.

Comment: A very minor point, `US/Eastern` is deprecated. Use `America/New_York` instead. It gives the same result. Or `America/Toronto` if in Canada wanting Eastern Time. Modern time zone ID format is *region/city*.